# Port Error exception when connecting HC-06 Device via Bluetooth 32Feet

Tags: c#, sockets, bluetooth, 32feet

I want to receive messages from [HC-06](http://www.puntoflotante.net/BLUETOOTH-HC-06-WITH-SERIAL-PORT-EASY-GUIDE.pdf) device to `PC`, I am using [32feet library](https://32feet.codeplex.com/) to manage Bluetooth, however whenever I tried to connect I get an exception.

`HC-06` uses the `SPP (Serial Port Profile)` so the idea is to use a virtual COM port in the device manager. And then use the `SerialPort` class to communicate.

## Exception

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException(0x80004005): A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond  *my bluetooth
>   address*: at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP) at
>   InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.SocketBluetoothClient.Connect(BluetoothEndPoint
>   remoteEP) at
>   InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient.Connect(BluetoothEndPoint
>   remoteEP) ....

## Current `C#` code:

```
string my_pin ="1234";  //default pin for HC-06 device
BluetoothAddress address = BluetoothAddress.Parse("201311111662"); //address of HC-06
BluetoothEndPoint ep = new BluetoothEndPoint(address, BluetoothService.SerialPort);
bool t = false;
BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(address, my_pin);
BluetoothClient cli = new BluetoothClient();
cli.Connect(ep);
t = cli.Connected;
```

Also I have tried using `RFCommProtocol` (service class) instead of `SerialPort` on the line
`BluetoothEndPoint ep = new BluetoothEndPoint(address, BluetoothService.SerialPort);` but had no success

To do some tests that HC-06 device is in fact sendind messages I used Realterm software to check it out, I assign in terminal COM8 PORT `8=\BthModem0` with baud rate `9600` and messages appear in terminal.
**BthModem directs all I/O and control operations to RfComm through a TDI interface**

What am I missing? Do I have to use virtual connection or something so I can get `HC-06` messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a "normal" Windows application (and not a Windows Store application), it's probably easier to use the [SerialPort class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: So, I would just use available `COMx` to read data sent from device?

Comment: Yes (some additional characters to satisfy the Add Comment button)